# How to obtain a StringIO that works with the str type?

Tags: python, unicode

As we know the `str` type has different meaning when it comes to version 2.x and version 3.x of the Python language. Unfortunately a number of frameworks and APIs expect to work with it disregarding the change in meaning and behaviour. Examples are the `logging` framework and the `WSGI` API. When a `logging.StreamHandler` writes to a stream, it writes `str`, not `bytes` and not `unicode`.

Non-options:

- `StringIO.StringIO`: is not available in Python 3.x
- `io.BytesIO`: fails when Python 3.x writes a `str` (i.e. unicode) to it
- `io.StringIO`: fails when Python 2.x writes a `str`  (i.e. `bytes`) to it

So how do I obtain a `StringIO` like object that works with `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`six` library](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) has a StringIO class that might work for you, [described as](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.StringIO):

> an alias for StringIO.StringIO in Python 2 and io.StringIO in Python 3.